# I cannot load Ubuntu in ACER 10 because i an very new in this community and i need help in about ubuntu.

Tags: acer

I have a laptop ACER 10, and when I try to load Ubuntu I get back an error that says:

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU -please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.
```

Please let me know what to do, in order to load Ubuntu.

Comment: Download and install the 32bit version of Ubuntu. https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads. If it's an oldish machine, you may also get better performance with one of the lighter versions of Ubuntu, such as Lubuntu or Ubuntu MATE.

Answer (score 0):

This means you are trying to run a 64-bit version of Ubuntu while your computer only supports the 32-bit version. You should **get the 32-bit Intel** / x86 / i686 / i386 version (several terms for the same thing…).

Since the version to download is chosen by the architecture of the computer where you are downloading it, you may rather want to choose the image manually at http://releases.ubuntu.com/.

As JonasCz [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885281/i-cannot-load-ubuntu-in-acer/885284#comment1381857_885281) already, you should consider choosing a lighter edition of *ubuntu. For example, [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) is my favorite. There are more, like [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/), [Ubuntu GNOME](https://ubuntugnome.org/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) which is considered to be the lightest one.